# How to add images specific to android tablet in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

While I was trying to add images specifically for android tablets in drawable-sw600dp and drawable-sw720dp folder.The images are getting scaled twice that the actual sizes. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use screen density qualifiers as well. See: 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_4_-_creating_resources_for_varying_screens/#Concepts

> A few terms and concepts are important to understand in order to support multiple screens.
>
> Screen Size – The amount of physical space for displaying your application
>
> Screen Density – The number of pixels in any given area on the screen. The typical unit of measure is dots per inch (dpi).
>
> Resolution – The total number of pixels on the screen. When developing applications, resolution is not as important as screen size and density.
>
> Density-independent pixel (dp) – This is a virtual unit of measure to allow layouts to be designed independent of density. To convert dp into screen pixels the following formula is used: px=dp*dpi/160

There is a good chart of all of the qualifiers you can use here:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_3_-_alternate_resources/

For screen density there are these qualifiers:

> Screen pixel density (dpi)
>   The number of pixels in a given area on the physical screen. Typically expressed as dots per inch (dpi).
>
> Possible values are:
>
> ldpi - Low density screens.
>
> mdpi - Medium density screens
>
> hdpi - High density screens
>
> xhdpi - Extra high density screens
>
> nodpi - Resources that are not to be scaled
>
> tvdpi - Introduced in API level 13 (Android 3.2) for screens between mdpi and hdpi.